# Validar Data model con dataannotations en BLAZOR WEBASSEMBLY

Tags: validación, blazor

Tengo el siguiente datamodel (Conformado por otras clases)

```
public class DMMovimientoEntity
{
    public MovimientoEntity Movimiento = new MovimientoEntity();
    public MovimientoPagoEntity MovimientoPago = new MovimientoPagoEntity();
    public MovimientoAdjuntoEntity MovimientoAdjunto = new MovimientoAdjuntoEntity();

}
```

Todas las clases que conforman el data model tienen atributos de validación, por ejemplo:

```
public class MovimientoPagoEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int MovimientoPagoId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int MovimientoId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double ValorPago { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime f_crea { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime f_mod { get; set; }
    public MovimientoEntity Movimiento { get; set; }
}
```

En el formulario, al hacer clic en el botón de Guardado no se genera ninguna validación (Pasa de largo) a ejecutar el método de guardado. En el formulario sólo asigné la etiqueta para mostrar la validación de un campo (Comprendo que debe ponerse para todos los campos con validación, no lo hice para que el código esté mas corto, si funciona para uno será igual para los demás ).

/*

```
    //Importar
    
    @using Entities;
    @using Entities.DataModel;
    @using Business;
    @using Business.DataModel;   
    @inject IToastService ToastService

<EditForm Model="objDMMovimiento" OnValidSubmit="@GuardarMovimiento">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <h3 class="text-capitalize text-center">CREAR MOVIMIENTOS</h3>

    <hr />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold">Tipo Documento</label>
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.DocumentoTipoId" class="form-control col-md-4">
                @foreach (var item in ListaDocumentoTipo)
                {
                    <option value="@item.DocumentoTipoId">@item.Descripcion</option>
                }
            </InputSelect>
            &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.DocumentoTipoId)"></ValidationMessage>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold">Fecha Documento</label>
            <InputDate @bind-Value="objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.FechaDocumento" class="col-md-4 form-control"></InputDate>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold">Persona</label>
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.PersonaId" class="form-control col-md-4">
                @foreach (var item in ListaPersonas)
                {
                    <option value="@item.PersonaId">@item.NombreCompleto</option>
                }
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold">Ejecutor</label>
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.EjecutorPucId" class="form-control col-md-4">
                @foreach (var item in ListaPucEjecutor)
                {
                    <option value="@item.PucId">@item.Descripcion</option>
                }
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold">Numero Documento</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.DocumentoProveedor" class="form-control col-md-4" placeholder="Número Factura-Documento" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold">Descripción</label>
            <InputTextArea @bind-Value="objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.Descripcion" class="form-control col-md-4" placeholder="Descripción Gasto o Costo" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold">Valor Documento</label>
            <InputNumber @bind-Value="objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.ValorDocumento" class="form-control col-md-4" placeholder="Valor Factura-Documento" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold">Valor Iva</label>
            <InputNumber @bind-Value="objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.ValorIva" class="form-control col-md-4" placeholder="Valor Iva" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold">Valor Retefuente</label>
            <InputNumber @bind-Value="objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.ValorRetefuente" class="form-control col-md-4" placeholder="Valor Retefuente" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold">Ceco Gasto </label>
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.CecoId" class="form-control col-md-4">
                @foreach (var item in ListaCeco)
                {
                    <option value="@item.CecoId">@item.Descripcion</option>
                }
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold">Valor Pago</label>
            <InputNumber @bind-Value="objDMMovimiento.MovimientoPago.ValorPago" class="form-control col-md-4" @onfocus="CalcularPago" placeholder="Valor Pagado" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold">Pagador</label>
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.PagadorPucId" class="form-control col-md-4">
                @foreach (var item in ListaPucPagador)
                {
                    <option value="@item.PucId">@item.Descripcion</option>
                }
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar Movimiento" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {

    //Definición de variables

    DMMovimientoEntity objDMMovimiento = new DMMovimientoEntity();
    private string mensage = "";
    private int rta_crear = 0;
    List<DocumentoTipoEntity> ListaDocumentoTipo = new List<DocumentoTipoEntity>();
    List<PersonaEntity> ListaPersonas = new List<PersonaEntity>();
    List<PucEntity> ListaPucEjecutor = new List<PucEntity>();
    List<PucEntity> ListaPucPagador = new List<PucEntity>();
    List<CecoEntity> ListaCeco = new List<CecoEntity>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ListaDocumentoTipo = DocumentoTipoBusiness.ListarDocumentoTipo();
        ListaPersonas = PersonaBusiness.ListarPersona();
        ListaPucEjecutor = PucBusiness.ListarPuc(1);
        ListaPucPagador = PucBusiness.ListarPuc(2);
        ListaCeco = CecoBusiness.ListarCeco();
        objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.FechaDocumento = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void GuardarMovimiento()
    {
        objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.Consecutivo = 0;
        objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.f_crea = DateTime.Now;
        objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.f_mod = DateTime.Now;
        objDMMovimiento.MovimientoPago.f_crea = DateTime.Now;
        objDMMovimiento.MovimientoPago.f_mod = DateTime.Now;
        rta_crear = DMMovimientoBusiness.CrearMovimiento(objDMMovimiento);
        if (rta_crear > 0)
        {
            ToastService.ShowSuccess("Registro " + rta_crear + " Guardado!");

            objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.MovimientoId = 0;
            objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.DocumentoTipoId = 0;
            objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.Consecutivo = 0;
            objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.PersonaId = 0;
            objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.DocumentoProveedor = "0";
            objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.EjecutorPucId = 0;
            objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.Descripcion = "";
            objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.CecoId = 0;
            objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.ValorDocumento = 0;
            objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.ValorIva = 0;
            objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.ValorRetefuente = 0;
            objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.PagadorPucId = 0;

            objDMMovimiento.MovimientoPago.MovimientoPagoId = 0;
            objDMMovimiento.MovimientoPago.MovimientoId = 0;
            objDMMovimiento.MovimientoPago.ValorPago = 0;

            objDMMovimiento.MovimientoAdjunto.MovimientoAdjuntoId = 0;

        }
        else
        {
            ToastService.ShowError("Registro No guardado!");
        }


    }

    private void CalcularPago()
    {
        objDMMovimiento.MovimientoPago.ValorPago = objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.ValorDocumento + objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.ValorIva - objDMMovimiento.Movimiento.ValorRetefuente;
    }
}
```

*/

Al hacer clic en el botón, no se muestra ninguna validación.
Para un formulario de un maestro, se asocia un model (solo atributos) al formulario, funciona normalmente.
Para un formulario asociado a un data model (es conformados por varias clases), no sé como hacer la validación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Existe un paquete nuget blazored.fluentvalidation, funciona muy bien para validar formularios que dependen de una clase, pero cuando se surte el mismo procedimiento para validar formularios que dependen de data models (Clase compuesta por múltiples clases) no funciona.